# Override ExecutorSubscribableChannel in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-websocket, spring-messaging

For the purpose of custom logic I'd need to override  ExecutorSubscribableChannel  in Spring (Websocket side). How I can possibly do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not clear what are you going to override there, but extending `AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer` provides for you:

```
@Override
public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
}

@Override
public void configureClientOutboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
}
```

hooks and that `ChannelRegistration` lets you to specify any possible options on the `ExecutorSubscribableChannel`.